# How to test for significant difference between 2 binary variables in one sample

Tags: statistical-significance, spss, repeated-measures, binary-data

I would like to test if there is a significant difference between the pre-test and post-test in a dichotomous variable (0 = "False", 1 = "True"). I'm using only one sample of 30 subjects.

So, my 2 variables are:

- accuracy_pre_test (0 = "False", 1 ="True")
- accuracy_post_test (0 = "False", 1 ="True")

Also, I would appreciate if you can give me a general idea of how to perform this test in SPSS.

Comment: Could you tell us a little more about your sample? How many items are in your variable, and how many individuals are in the sample?

Comment: @doug.numbers additional information provided in the OP.

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks for your answer, however do you think there is another way so I dont have to rearrange the data?

Comment: Actually, mat, sorry, it just occurred to me that your data are paired. You don't want that you want a McNemar test.

Comment: Here are some relevant answers relating to that - [1](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/31578/805) [2](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/55527/805) [3](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/14453/805)

Comment: @Glen_b I think I'll perform a McNemar test. Thank you for your help!